# Ключ лицензии для android-приложения у разработчика одинаковый или для каждого приложения разный?

Tags: android

Я задался этим вопросом, т.к. хочу выпустить своё 2 приложение на платной основе, но не могу найти информацию о ключе. В панели разработчика я нашёл ключ, но он находится для конкретного приложения, т.е. я получаю ключ после того, как он уже будет залит в google? Но какой в этом смысл, если мне заранее надо его обезопасить. Получится, что первая версия будет без ключа, а меня это не устраивает. Поделитесь советом по этому поводу, заранее благодарен!

Comment: Разобрался с тем, что ключи формируются для конкретных приложений, а не 1 ключ на разработчика. Данная информация по ссылке: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=ru

В подвопросе (жирным почерком) "Как работает сервер лицензирования?".

Но тогда остаётся всё тот же вопрос. Как мне получить ключ заранее для приложения? В голову лишь приходит 1 мысль, что нужно, сначала выпускать Beta версию, но тогда придётся выпускать следом новую версию и писать в "что нового", что был добавлен ключ лицензии или любую другую отмазку, но это же бред...

Answer (score 2):

Всё,сам разобрался, как решить этот вопрос. Я забыл, что можно добавить своё приложение, но предварительно не заливать APK. Т.е. при нажатии кнопки "Добавить своё приложение" нам предоставляют выбор с чего начать: 1)Залить APK или 2)Начать с описания. Выбираем 2 пункт и приложение будет в списке, там же можно будет просмотреть его собственный ключ. 
Спасибо мне!